# Select2 does not appear correctly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have a problem to display select2 correctly. I have a simple code all sources from CDN which looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Drom/index.php</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form action="drom/index.php" class="form-group">
                <select name="type[]" id="x" class="form-control" id="frm-timeline-typeFilter-type" multiple="" data-autosubmit="1" data-select2-id="frm-timeline-typeFilter-type" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="contract" data-select2-id="3">Centrálny register zmlúv</option>
                    <option value="kataster" data-select2-id="4">Kataster</option>
                    <option value="kore" data-select2-id="5">Konkurzy a reštrukturalizácie</option>
                    <option value="likv" data-select2-id="6">Likvidácie a zrušenia</option>
                    <option value="debt" data-select2-id="7">Podlžnosti</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<script>
    (function ($)
    {
        $('#x').select2();
    }(jQuery));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the result looks like the screenshot below:
[image]
Does somebody know what is wrong with that? You can copy and past all the code and it will work as is. Please help me. It drives me crazy...

**EDIT**: There are two ides but if I remove the first one it looks like the picture below:

[image]

Comment: It does perfectly work!

Comment: It works just fine for me, maybe you got some styles that is overruling the default by select2

Comment: All the styles are in the code. What styles do you mean?

Comment: You have added two `id ` properties of  `select` control try removing the second one `id="frm-timeline-typeFilter-type"`.

Comment: You are right, there are two ides, but now it shows me "search" instead of items. Like in edited picture in question.

Comment: Select2 has a built in search filter for options. This is a feature, NOT a bug. look up `minimumResultsForSearch` in the docs https://select2.org/configuration/options-api

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's a combination of a typo and not reading the documentation.

Comment: You are right. The code is copy past with select2 attributes generated with js library which caused this problems...